# Using Laradock, the "display_errors" flag is not working

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laradock

I have change `display_errors = off` to `display_errors = On` in `php-fpm/php70.ini` and `laravel.ini`, and restarted the nginx and php-fpm, but when I refresh the phpinfo page, it shows display_errors is still off.

So I can't display the php errors on the page.
Could you tell me how to fix it, thanks.

I am using Mac.
And I found when I changed some configs in `php70.ini`, something is working, something is not working.

For example, I changed the `display_startup_errors` from `Off` to `On`, it worked and in phpinfo page it showed "On".

Hope somebody could tell me Why?

Comment: here is the laradock/php-fpm https://github.com/laradock/laradock/files/947367/php-fpm.zip

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the reason.

Because the `laravel.ini` doesn't reload.

I have modified display error from `Off` to `On` in the `laravel.ini` in `laradock/php-fpm/`, and executed

```
docker-compose stop
```

then ran

```
docker composer up -d nginx mysql
```

but when I enter the php-fpm container, I find the `laravel.ini` still not changed, it hasn't reloaded or updated.

Because the `laravel.ini` is loaded by ADD method in

`laradock/php-fpm/Dockerfile-70 line321:`

```
ADD ./laravel.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
ADD ./laravel.pool.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/
```

Answer : [github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/832](http://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/832)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was necessary to execute the following command:

```
docker-compose up --force-create --build (nginx or apache)
```

Hope this helps!